# Basic python defining function

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I'm having difficulty applying my knowledge of defining functions with def to my own function.

I want to create a function where I can filter my data frame based on my 1. columns I'd like to drop + their axis 2. using .dropna

I've used it on one of my data frames like this :

`total_adj_gross = ((gross.drop(columns = ['genre','rating', 'total_gross'], axis = 1)).dropna())`

I've also used it on another data frame like this :

`vill = (characters.drop(columns = ['hero','song'], axis = 1)).dropna(axis = 0)`

Can I make a function using def so I can easily do this to any data frame?

if so would I go about it like this

```
def filtered_df(data, col_name, N=1): 
 frame = data.drop(columns = [col_name], axis = N)
 frame.dropna(axis = N) 

 return frame
```

I can already feel like this above function would go wrong because what if I have different N's like in my vill object?

BTW I am a very new beginner as you can tell -- I haven't been exposed to any complex functions any help would be appreciated!

---

Update since I dont know how to make a code in comments:

Thank you all for your help in creating my function
but now how do I insert this in my code?

Do I have to make a script (.py) then call my function?

can I test in within my actual code?

right now if I just copy + paste any code in, and fill the column name I get an error saying the specific column code "is not found in the axis"

Comment: `dropna()` is not in place as default. You have to store the returned the returned value into frame like you did the line above.

Comment: Hi Ben so where I have frame.dropna(axis = N), I would write frame2 = frame.dropna(axis = N) -- should I store it in the same object? or even better can I/should I chain it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you want to achieve, you don't need to pass any axis parameter. Also, you want to pass a list of columns as a parameter to drop the different columns (axis=1 for `drop()` and axis=0 for `dropna()`, which is the default parameter value). And finally, `dropna()` is not in place by default. You have to store the returned value into a frame like you did the line above.

Your function should look like that:

```
def filtered_df(data, col_names): 
 frame = data.drop(columns = col_names, axis = 1)
 result = frame.dropna() 
 return result
```

Comment: When I plug this function in and run this code : 'total_adj_gross = ((gross.drop(columns = ['genre','rating', 'total_gross'], axis = 1)).dropna())' using filtered_df I get an error saying ['genre','rating', 'total_gross'] not found in axis -- what am I doing wrong? I am accessing the function by using filtered_df(total_adj_gross, ['genre','rating', 'total_gross'])

Answer (score 0):

Overall, code looks good. I'd suggest 3 minor changes:-

1. Pass columns names as list. Do not convert them to list within the functions
2. Pass 2 variables for working with axis. From what i see in your eg, your axis values changes for drop and dropna. Not sure about your need for it. If you want 2 diff axis values for `drop()` and `dropna()` then please use 2 diff variables, probably like `drop_axis` and `dropna_axis`.
3. assigning modified frame / single line operation

So, code would look something like this:-

```
def filtered_df(data, col_name, drop_axis=1, dropna_axis=0): 
    frame = data.drop(columns = col_name, axis = drop_axis).dropna(axis = dropna_axis)
    return frame
```

Your call to it can look like:

```
modified_df = filtered_df(data, ["x_col","y_col"], 0, 0)
```

Comment: every time I call the function like filtered_df(total_adj_gross, ['genre']) the error I get is KeyError: "[('genre',)] not found in axis" -- what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @snealvala can you post the header of the df you are passing?

Comment: RangeIndex: 579 entries, 0 to 578
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                    --------------  -----         
 0   movie_title               579 non-null    object        
 1   release_date              579 non-null    datetime64[ns]
 2   genre                     562 non-null    object        
 3   MPAA_rating               523 non-null    object        
 4   total_gross               579 non-null    object        
 5   inflation_adjusted_gross  579 non-null    object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(5)

Comment: if thats what header of the df is ^

Comment: I can make it work but now its not dropping the non null values with dropna

Comment: @snealvala Can you execute the command: data.columns or data.head() ?
Please update the response in your original question if the response is huge.